# Cloud Functions for Firebase to convert base64 string and save as image and thumbnail in firebase storage also update the node with the download urls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a node with pushid,name of person and base64 string as img.

1. I need to write a Cloud Functions for Firebase to convert the base64 string to image and also thumbnail and save both to firebase storage
2. also update the node  with one with image downloadurl and thumbnail url

Comment: Sounds like a cool list of requirements. What's your question?

Comment: i have a node contacts/{pushid} and whenever any data is written in the node with following fields pushid,name,image ( base64 string). It would trigger a database functions to create image and thumbnail against the base64 string and save the images in firebase storage.
2. after storing images it would update image url and thumbnail url to this   
pushid  fields imageurl and thumburl.